# Second Select Won't POST

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I have a form that includes two `<select>` tags:

```
<li>
    <label for="uname">Select User : </label>
    <select id="uname" name="uname">
        <option value="3">Kaine McAuley</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <label for="uweek">Week Number : </label>
    <select id="uweek" name="uweek">
        <option value="1">Week 1</option>
        <option value="2">Week 2</option>
        <option value="3">Week 3</option>
        <option value="4">Week 4</option>
        <option value="5">Week 5</option>
        <option value="6">Week 6</option>
        <option value="7">Week 7</option>
        <option value="8">Week 8</option>
        <option value="9">Week 9</option>
        <option value="10">Week 10</option>
        <option value="11">Week 11</option>
        <option value="12">Week 12</option>
    </select>
</li>
```

That's how it comes out in the browser. I have `echo`'d the contents of `$_POST` and `uweek` doesn't exist in there. However, `uname` does!

My actual PHP code that creates the form is as follows:

```
echo '<h2>Update Users</h2><form action="" method="post">
    <ul style="list-style: none;">
            <li>
            <label for="uname">Select User : </label>
            <select id="uname" name="uname">';
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    switch($r['Username'])
    {
        case 'Mike':
        case '3rungohan':
        case 'Test':
        case 'Jestress':break;
        default: echo '<option value="' . $r['UserID'] . '">' . $r['RealName'] . '</option>';
    }
}

echo '</select></li>
<li>
    <label for="uweek">Week Number : </label>
    <select id="uweek" name="uweek">';
    for($i=1;$i<13;$i++)
    {
        $week = "Week " . $i;
        echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $week . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>
</li>
<li>
    <label for="uaims">Week Aims : </label><br />
    <textarea id="uaims" name="uaims" rows="4" cols="40" required="required"></textarea>
</li>
<li>
    <label for="upros">Week Progress : </label><br />
    <textarea id="upros" name="upros" rows="4" cols="40" required="required"></textarea>
</li>
<li>
    <label for="unote">Week Notes : </label><br />
    <textarea id="unote" name="unote" rows="4" cols="40" required="required" placeholder="If no notes, just enter: No notes"></textarea>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</li>
</ul>
</form>';
```

Results of `print_r($_POST);`

```
Array ( [uname] => 3 [uaims] => Aims [upros] => Nope [unote] => No )
```

Similar results from `var_dump($_REQUEST);`

```
array(4) { ["uname"]=> string(1) "3" ["uaims"]=> string(4) "Aims" ["upros"]=> string(4) "Nope" ["unote"]=> string(2) "No" }
```

Once `$_POST` executes and goes through, my code (at the top of the php document):
Sorry for the endless queries I needed several rounds of info from different tables.

```
if(!empty($_POST['uname']))
{
    foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {$up[$k] = $v;}
    $sql2 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM jestresstracker WHERE UserID='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $up['uname']) ."' ORDER BY WeekNum DESC LIMIT 1");
    $temp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2);
    $sql3 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM jestress_users WHERE UserID='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $up['uname']) ."' LIMIT 1");
    $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql3);
    foreach($r as $k => $v) {$User[$k] = $v;}
    if(!empty($temp['WeekNum']))
    {
        if($up['uweek']<=$temp['WeekNum']) {$result = "Error. Update already set for this week. Week Num: " . $temp['WeekNum'];}
    }
    else {
        $ins = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO jestresstracker (UserID, WeekNum, WeekAims, WeekPro, Updated, UpdatedBy, Notes) VALUES('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $up['uname']) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $up['uweek']) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, nl2br($up['uaims'])) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, nl2br($up['upros'])) . "', NOW(), '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $res['UserID']) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, nl2br($up['unote'])) . "')");
        if($ins) {$result = "Successfully updated " . $User['RealName'] . "'s Week " . $up['uweek'] . " post.";var_dump($_REQUEST);}
        else {$result = "Error: " . mysqli_error($link);}
    }
}
```

EDIT: Changing the id/name doesn't return different results.

Comment: how did you checked that? show us the result of `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Given what is shown, it should work. Perhaps try a `var_dump($_REQUEST);`

Comment: Please follow the advice of @jason. Edit your post with the results of print_r($POST); If you still do not see uweek, Please include the php of your processing logic.

Comment: Are you sure the select is within the form tags?

Comment: @Daniel Yes the select is within the form, it's the second element and the others below it are passed to `$_POST`

Comment: do you have any javascript code or jquery?

Comment: No JS or jQuery on this page. None that might affect the outcome.

Comment: can you share the URL of that page (if possible) and let me just see the source code and check something

Comment: I have switched the second `<select>` element for a selection radio buttons instead. This is working fine, I can deal with this, however, I would very much like to understand why the 2 `<select>` elements collided? Can't think of anything else that may cause this?

Comment: @JasonOOO Here's the web address, moved it to a temp location so you can look at it! http://main.thanetdragons.co.uk/jestressflo/parkour-tracker/form.php

Comment: Quick test of the form with a simulated first select submits both `selects` to `S_POST`. What does a dump on $r give, when it rolls out the database?

Comment: If you refer to your temp location, I get a login screen there. I am not able to see.

Answer (score 1):

The best friend here in such situation is firebug or any network analysis tool..

Check the headers and make sure that concerned field is indeed posted through..

I think this may help greatly..

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is something wrong with your php or webserver. Try to create `$_POST` array yourself using this function:

```
function decodePost(){
    $var = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $postContent = explode('&',$var);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($postContent); $i++){
        $postContent[$i] = urldecode($postContent[$i]);
        $map = explode('=', $postContent[$i]);
        $post[$map[0]] = $map[1];
    }
    return $post;   
}
```

And see whether anything changes.

Comment: I am getting exactly the same results, still no `uweek` included in the array.

Comment: @MikeShaw Maybe something wrong with your browser? Try adding one more option in that select: `<option value='100' selected>Test`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give all the HTML code with the form and all the fields.

Do you have many of them ? Are they big/long ?

Do you have limitation in your `php.ini` configuration ? Check `post_max_size` value.

Do you have suhosin module installed on your server ? (check `phpinfo()` to be sure).
Suhosin may be tricky sometimes, it logs in system logs (eg. `/var/log/syslog`) instead of logging in webserver logs (eg. Apache logs).

Try checking these default values in `suhosin.ini` :

```
suhosin.post.max_array_depth = 100
suhosin.post.max_array_index_length = 64
suhosin.post.max_name_length = 64
suhosin.post.max_totalname_length = 256
suhosin.post.max_value_length = 1000000
suhosin.post.max_vars = 1000
```

Also check your HTML code with [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/), to be sure everything is correctly formatted. Maybe your browser acts weirdly because of that.

Do you have jQuery `onSubmit` function or something catching the submit in the Javascript code ?